# button type value is different in IE & FF

Tags: php, html

I'm using a form containing a button type shown below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<button type=submit value="hello" name="submitform">World</button>
</form>
```

Here the button type shows different behavior on different browsers

now `print_r($_POST)` display

```
Array
(
    [submitform] => World
)
 In IE(v 7.0)
```

whereas

```
Array
(
    [submitform] => Hello
)
in FF(v 3.5)
```

Why does it display different value...
**now my questions are:**

1. I want  `[submitform]=Hello` in both browser  and I don't want to change the value 'World' outside of `<button>`
2. Is `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit">` better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could substitute the button's information with a hidden input field:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <button type="submit">World</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitform" value="hello" />
</form>
```

This is a browserquirks save method.

Another possibility, although way less elegant, is to use an image:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="image" src="my_World_image.gif" name="submitform" value="hello" />
</form>
```

Advantage: You can have multiple submit buttons submiting different values.

Disadvantage: As David Dorward mentioned, most probably you will face the same problem again because of buggy implementations, namely IE's.

The third possibility is JavaScript, but you will encounter all sorts of problems for users having disabled it (I warned you!):

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitform" value="" id="changeme" />
<button type="button" onclick="do_submission('hello')">Submit Hello</button>
<button type="button" onclick="do_submission('world')">Submit World</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function do_submission(value) {
  document.getElementById('changeme').value = value;
  document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this not the solution you want? The only case when this differs from your question is, when you have multiple submit buttons. And in that case you have either to abandon the "World" inside the button or to add some error-prone JavaScript.

Comment: This won't work. Some browsers don't send the value for image inputs, just the coordinates.

Comment: @David Dorward: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I always use `<input type="submit" value="Whatever I want the button label to be" />` and it's worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Well with `button` you can have arbitrary text or images inside the button. This is not possible with `input` afaik. The value is always also the buttons text.

If IE has this strange behaviour then it seems you have no other choice as to keep the value of the button and the text in it the same (which is exactly what `input` is doing).

Answer (score 1):

`<button>` is horribly broken in MSIE. `<input type="submit">` doesn't let you have the label be different to the value.

The work around is to use `<input type="submit">` and give each one a unique name, then [search to find which one was successful](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html).